# In the following code, why isn't the if-else statement giving res equal to true? (for c2[i]==0)

Tags: java

In this code snippet, I was expecting res of c2[i]=0 to be true, but its actual output is coming out to be false.
Code:

```
if( res==false && c2.length>n ){
            System.out.println("c2[i] "+c2[i]);
            if(c2[i]>0){
                res = false;
            }
            else{
                res = true;
            }
        }
System.out.println("res "+res);
```

Output:

```
c2[i] 0
res false
c2[i] 4
res false
_
```

---

**Complete function:**
I'm trying to write a comparison-based algorithm. The takes two strings as input (characters are integers). The algorithm should output true if s1>s2.
e.g. s1 = 3 and s2 = 30 => res = true
e.g. s1 = 30 and s2 = 34 => red = false
This is the approach I tried:

```
Boolean isGreaterThan(String s1, String s2){
        char[] c1 = s1.toCharArray();
        char[] c2 = s2.toCharArray();
        boolean res = true;
        int i=0;
        int n = Math.min(c1.length, c2.length);
        for(i=0; i<n; i++){
            if(c1[i]<=c2[i]){
                res = false;
            }
            else{
                res = true;
            }
        }
        if( res==false && c2.length>n ){
            System.out.println("c2[i] "+c2[i]);
            if(c2[i]>0){
                res = false;
            }
            else{
                res = true;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("res "+res);
        return res;
}
```

Comment: In `for(i=0; i<n; i++){` the first iteration maybe true, then the second iteration false.  I think your logic is incorrect.  Why not convert the Strings to `Integer` and then compare?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the for loop, you're overwriting the value of `res` with each iteration of the loop. As a result, the final value of res depends on the comparison made in the last iteration of the loop. As a result, the final value of `res` depends on the comparison made in the last iteration of the loop.

Instead of setting `res` to `true` or `false` based on a single comparison, you should be checking whether the condition `c1[i] > c2[i]` is satisfied. If it is, then `res` should be set to `true`, otherwise it should remain unchanged. In addition to that, you need to stop the loop as soon as the comparison condition is met, because you're only interested in the leftmost differing characters.

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (c1[i] > c2[i]) {
        res = true;
        break; 
    } else if (c1[i] < c2[i]) {
        res = false;
        break; 
    }
}

if (res == false && c2.length > n) {
    if (c2[n] > 0) {
        res = false;
    } else {
        res = true;
    }
}
```